# How does durability work in Breath of the Wild?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

In the tool tips, the game always says to "keep an eye on your durability" or that certain actions might "knock off some durability", but so far I have only seen 3 stages of durability: Fine, damaged, and broken.

Is there any way to track how much durability a weapon or shield has remaining, in terms of "uses" or percentage durability?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**No, there's no way to know exactly how many hits you have left in a weapon through a percentage, durability bar, or other exact indicator.**

The game gives you 3 signals for durability before a weapon breaks:

*Completely unused*, which is denoted by a yellow flashing star in the upper right corner of the weapon slot in your inventory:

[image: Undamaged weapon]

*Used, but not close to breaking*, which is denoted by the yellow flashing star disappearing from the corner of the weapon slot in your inventory.

*Damaged and close to breaking*, which is denoted by a red flashing background in the weapon slot in your inventory.

Comment: Oh wow! I didn't even realise that's what that star meant!

Comment: Not worth mentioning on an answer, but when it's flashing red, that means that it has 3 hits left, so you can hit twice and then throw it to deal 2x damage.

Comment: Four years later: there is a way. Using a glitch called IST, it's possible to transfer any item's durability onto an arrow count. Dividing the resulting number by 100 will give you the exact durability of the item. For example, transferring an undamaged, unmodified Hylian Shield's durability onto regular arrows will give you 80,000 arrows. Dividing by 100 gives 800 durability.