# Does dry-firing bows decrease durability?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

In *Breath of the Wild*, you can fire bows without having any arrows. Does it decrease the weapons’ durability at all?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Excellent question. I was really curious about this so I did some googling and found nothing. But I still wanted to know so I tested it myself. I grabbed my self 2 boko bows and tested how many shots it would take to break, and if the same amount of "dry-fires" would break it.

The boko bow shot 16 arrows before it fully broke. With the second bow I fired 16 blanks and it didnt break. So I fired another 16 blanks and it still didnt break. Finally, I fired 16 arrows and it broke on the last one.

So to conclude, dry-firing a bow does **not** cause it to lose durability. (And it takes 16 shots to break a boko bow).

Comment: Also, you can sort of ["track" durability](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/330761/how-does-durability-work-in-breath-of-the-wild). If you pick up a new bow, it will have a sparkling start to indicate it's "pristine" condition. If this changes, it does mean that the item does decrease in durability, even after the first try (i.e. 99/100 durability the sparkle will disappear).